# How can I remove suffix of string in cut result (bash)?

Tags: string, bash, awk, cut

I want to remove all characters after specific char "/" in all result lines of `cut` command
How may I do that using bash commands?

for example if `cut -f2 file` results :

```
John.Micheal/22
Erik.Conner/19
Damian.Lewis/40
```

I need this on output:

```
John.Micheal
Erik.Conner
Damian.Lewis
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pipe it to another `cut`, using `/` as the field separator:

```
cut -f2 file | cut -f1 -d/
```

Or you could use `sed` to cut off everything beyond `/`:

```
cut -f2 file | sed 's?/.*??'
```

Or you could use a single `awk` with a custom field separator, assuming there are no `/` in the first field:

```
awk -F'[\t/]' '{print $2}' file
```

If there can be `/` in the first field then it's better to use the first two suggestions.

Comment: Your `awk` command assumes there are no `/` in the first tab-delimited field.

Answer (score 0):

Or use pure bash `while` loop to read line by line into a shell variable. One option:

```
cut -f2 file | while IFS=/ read -r a _; do echo "$a"; done
```

Another option:

```
cut -f2 file | while read -r a; do echo "${a%/*}"; done
```

First one uses IFS word splitting during read, another uses parameter expansion.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing what you file looks like, it's better to pipe the result of `cut -f2 file` to another `cut` or `awk` or `sed` as suggested by @janos, or use @kastelian's method

since `cut -f2 file` gives you

```
John.Micheal/22
Erik.Conner/19
Damian.Lewis/40
```

I am guessing this is what your original file looks like

```
ab/c    John.Micheal/22 abc/23
de      Erik.Conner/df  abc
        Damian.Lewis/40 def/999
```

instead of `cut` and pipe the output to another command, you can get the result directly
to get the string between the first tab and the first / after tab

```
 sed  's@^[^\t]*[\t]\+\([^/]\+\)/.*@\1@' file
```

or if you have GNU sed

```
 sed -r 's@^[^\t]*[\t]+([^/]+)/.*@\1@' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk for the whole thing:

```
awk -F'\t' '{split($2,a,"/"); print a[1]}' file
```

If there are no other "/"s in your first 2 fields then you can reduce to:

```
awk -F'[\t/]' '{print $2}' file
```